# Random GUID in Java (A different format)

Tags: java, random, guid, uuid

One of the components that I use needs to feed an XML into it. The component provider has not provided any documentation or the specs of the XML. I am trying to generate the XMLs by trial and error using the sample XMLs from the component.

This was the story. Here is my problem.
In the XML, they have used some `f_key = "b3f39bb9-3f8c-453a-bdb4-2486a887e39f-0000a008:000001e8"`

Java gives me this : `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`
which generates random strings in this format : `"22572e59-f7dc-404a-9c0c-78161e3a4df7"`

Any clue, what does "`0000a008:000001e8`" in the f_key provided by the component mean [The random string up to 5 pieces matches in both. The 6th and 7th piece are extra in the random string provided by the component]? What sort of UUID generator would be generating that? Does it look familiar?

Comment: *"The 6th and 7th piece are extra in the **random** string provided by the component"* [sic]... The probability that *"0000a008"* and/or *"000001e8"* would be random is **very** low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this code

```
Regex guidRegEx = new Regex(@"^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$");
guidRegEx.IsMatch("b3f39bb9-3f8c-453a-bdb4-2486a887e39f-0000a008:000001e8");
```

that isn't a valid guid, its a valid guid with something on the end. I am guessing they've tacked a timestamp on the end. I've seen stuff come out of timestamp appliances in the past.

But that is a best guess.

Comment: okay. Thanks. I guess I'll have to figure out what the 6th and 7th pieces are.

Comment: I didn't have to put the guid after all! I figured out it was optional and they generate it themselves. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is just some kind of key that is generated by the provider. Although I have no idea about the rules of the key generation (that is application specific) I translated hex numbers a008 1e8 to decimal view and found that the ratio between them is 83: `40968/488=83`. So, probably try to create UUID and add suffix that consists of 2 numbers in hex format so that the ration of them is 83.

Comment: nice thought. yes floor(40968/488) is 83 but the ratios are different in different XMLs.